# Are liqueur chocolates considered liquids at airport security?

Tags: france, airport-security, food-and-drink

as you may know, Christmas is coming.
My question is simple, if I offer a liqueur chocolates box to someone taking a plane after Christmas, will he be allow to take it on board or will he have to eat all the chocolate at the security post?

(the flight is an internal french flight - Nantes **NTE** to Lille **LIL**)

Comment: Why wouldn't they be allowed?

Comment: There is liquor, so as liquids (as water bottles) are not allowed, I'm wondering about liquored chocolates.

Comment: I suspect that in practice there's a 90% chance that the security folks wouldn't bat an eye at them, and the other 10% of the time you'd just have to surrender them.  If you're willing to take a chance, you could just bring them with you and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know the answer but it is probably based on the consistency of the liquor as usually it's almost caramel like - but why not by them the other side of security?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theoretically Travellers answer is right. If you have liquids in your carry on luggage, you have to fit them into the 1 liter plastic bag and each container has to have the amount of liquid declared on the packaging, which have to be less or equal to 100 ml.

I have however flown several times from Zürich in Switzerland to Paris in France while carrying Kirschstängeli ([Link to a shop that sells them](https://produkte.migros.ch/kirschstaengeli)) which are chocolates containing an fluid alcoholic filling. Nobody has ever taken them out of my bag or taken them away. I think the amount of fluid might be too little for them to notice / care.

Answer (score 3):

While France is not the USA, the liquid rules are practically the same in the US and the EU especially because they usually employ the same RapidScan liquid explosive detectors. With that said, the TSA officially allows liquid filled chocolates in https://twitter.com/tsa/status/566001348823744512?lang=en

> Regular and cream/liquid filled chocolates are good to go in carry-on bags!

Answer (score -2):

It would depend on the total amount of liquid in the chocolates and whether the passenger could fit them into the standard clear plastic bag required when passing through security.

https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/chocolate-liquid  And https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/chocolate-solid

Comment: I wouldn't think that TSA regulations would be directly relevant to an internal flight in France.

Comment: Point taken - the OP didn’t specify the airport, my assumption was that security rules tend to be similar globally

Comment: The rules for liquids are slightly different between the US and the EU. It is however the same that the rules apply to all kinds of liquids. There are neither in the US nor in the EU any special exceptions for chocolate fillings.

Comment: TSA links irrelevant, -1 and flagged as not an answer.

Comment: As many airport security rules follow the same liquid rules as the TSA, I think this is a valid link and it is an answer. If you think the answer is wrong, please post an answer you are sure is right.

Comment: ..or downvote it if you think it's wrong.  Another person may not have the answer but knows it's wrong.

Comment: Downvoters - Please give a reason. If you know the answer is factually wrong I am happy to delete it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Chocolate (liquid)" is referring to *the chocolate itself* being liquid (eg chocolate syrup), not liqueur-filled chocolates.