# Can I carry alcohol filled chocolate in hand luggage to Vienna

Tags: airport-security, hand-luggage, eu-citizens

We plan a two days trip to Vienna. Can I carry alcohol filled chocolate in my hand luggage? We are flying from Lisbon to Vienna.
I plan to take 6 boxes of 24 units, each unit containing about 1ml of liquor, for what I’m worried it might exceed the 125ml rule for hand luggage

Comment: [Are liqueur chocolates considered liquids at airport security?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/150711/are-liqueur-chocolates-considered-liquids-at-airport-security)